# Which type of variable is created in the code below

Tags: javascript, function, iterator, closures

In the code below is an iterator:

```js
const cart = ['Product 0','Product 1','Product 2','Product 3','Product 4','Product 5','Product 6','Product 7','Product 8','Product 9','Product 10']
function createIterator(cart) {
    let i = 0;//(*)

    return {
        nextProduct: function() {
            //i:0; (**)
            let end = (i >= cart.length);
            let value = !end ? cart[i++] : undefined;

            return {
                end: end,
                value: value
            };
        }
    };
}
const it = createIterator(cart);
```

First I know a copy of the present state of the function's variables and the parameters are parsed.**(Right?)**...
And when you run

```
const it = createIterator(cart);
```

**Is a property below created?**

```
//i:0 (**);
```

Making it.next(); equivalent to

```
{
i:0;//state or value of i from createIterator() definition;
next : function(cart){
        let end = (this.i >= cart.length);
                    let value = !end ? cart[this.i++] : undefined;

                    return {
                        end: end,
                        value: value
                    };
        }
```

Or does state of the value of i in line (*) from the first code, Is what's what is modified?
**Please if this point is not clear... let me know to explain better.**

Comment: I'm confused.  `it` will result in containing an object with a single key of `nextProduct` which has a function reference as a value.  Your last code snippet seems disconnected from the first one.

Comment: If you'd add `i` as a property as you've done in the last example, `it.i` will always be `0`. You need to add a getter function to the returned object to get a live value of `i` in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the iterator will create an instance of `i` scoped to the `createIterator` function. The object returned from it will only have access to that specific instance of `i`, but `i` **is not** a property of the object returned. It only can access it due to the function scope.

You can see a little better how this works if we break your code down a little more simply:

```js
function createIterator(cart, display) {
    let i = 0;
    return {
        next: function() {
            i++;
            console.log(display + ' next: ', i);
        }
    };
}

const cart1 = [];
const cart2 = [];

const it1 = createIterator(cart1, 'cart1');
it1.next();
it1.next();

const it2 = createIterator(cart2, 'cart2');
it2.next();
it2.next();
```

Each instance of the iterator has a **different** copy of `i` and only the object returned from the iterator function can access it.